# Searching Inside Mongo Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Here is my mongo Structure:

```
{
  "_id": "QEvgJKERy5xGNLv7J",
  "title": "test 2",
  "owner": "HQNGYZvrrdQRwLNvT",
  "markdown": "sdfasdfdasf adsfadsfasdf",
  "state": "Draft",
  "category": [
    "Bios & Memoirs",
    "Classics"
  ],
  "type": "Article",
  "lastupdate": "",
  "slug": "test-2",
  "date": 1504890635515,
  "views": "0",
  "rating": "0",
  "username": "gibigbig"
}
```

I would like to find all articles based on category. So something like:

`db.documents.find({category: 'Comedy'});`

but it doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since `category` is an array you can also use `$in:`

```
db.documents.find({ category: { $in: ['Comedy'] }});
```

It seems backwards since you're looking for the value `Comedy` inside the array but that's the way the syntax is defined. You can also perform a many-to-many match, i.e.

```
db.documents.find({ category: { $in: ['Comedy','Tragedy'] }});
```

or you can just do a straight up single-value search as you discovered:

```
db.documents.find({category: 'Comedy'});
```

Comment: Also can you explain what you mean by "it seems backwards" ?

Comment: "arrayname in value" when you're looking in the array for the value :)

Comment: Thanks again. Enjoy your day.

Answer (score 0):

`db.documents.find({category: 'Comedy'});`

My environment was off. Fixed and these queries now work.